# How to customize the daterangepicker(ngxDaterangepickerMd )

Tags: javascript, css, angular, typescript, bootstrap-4

I want to customize `daterangepicker` am using `ngxDaterangepickerMd` so that am getting `start date` in single input field i want to split `start date` and `end date` in two different fields so that if i do any modifications in `start date` or `end date` individually

```
<div class="col-lg-3 col-md-3 col-sm-6 col-xs-12 DC">
      <div class="form-group">
        <img src="./assets/icons/calender-01.svg" class="cImg">
        <input id="datepicker1" class="form-control dpFrom" type="text" name="daterange" placeholder="Departure"
                ngxDaterangepickerMd [(ngModel)]="selected" [minDate]="minDate" [showClearButton]="true"
        [singleDatePicker]="false">
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-lg-3 col-md-3 col-sm-6 col-xs-12 AC">
      <div class="form-group fff">
        <img src="./assets/icons/calender-01.svg" class="cImg">
        <input id="datepicker2" class="form-control dpTo" type="text" name="arrival" placeholder="Return">
      </div>
    </div>
```

Comment: Well, if you want start date and end date in two different fields, why're you using ngxDaterangePicker. Instead use Datepicker provided by angular-material. Have a look, it's easy to implement with the help of docs: https://material.angular.io/components/datepicker/overview

Comment: am using it because i need range in between two dates so am using this daterangepicker is there any daterangepicker with two fields  that is start date and end date.  I had done all my trials to customize the daterangepicker and finally am here  can you please refer me. Thank you

Answer (score 0):

Call a event function using (datesUpdated) on input tag in html

html:

```
<input (datesUpdated)="datesUpdated($evnets)"/>
```

ts:

```
datesUpdated(range){
console.log(range.startDate._d);
console.log(range.endDate._d);
}
```

store start date and end date in different blocked variables.